# I am looking for an introduction to hyperbolic surfaces as a quotient of the upper half plane by lattices.

Tags: reference-request, hyperbolic-geometry, lattices-in-lie-groups

I keep coming across results of the form: If we take the quotient of the upper half plane by a Fuchsian group with this property, we get a surface with that property (cusps, funnels, in/finite area, ...).

Could you recommend a reference for those kinds of results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few references to get you started:

- [Thurston's notes](http://library.msri.org/books/gt3m/) and the book form, *Geometry and Topology of 3-Manifolds*
- *Introduction to Teichmuller Theory*, by Hubbard
- *Lectures on Hyperbolic Geometry*, by Benedetti and Petronio